# Dota 2 lag spike every 10 seconds

Tags: dota-2

I get lag spikes every 10 seconds of playing the game and there are disconnection warning notices in the top right side, this keeps happening until the game ends. I tried to ping google while playing but the ping keeps on running. I play using my wifi connection. I also play on my PC which uses a lan cable and that seems to run smoothly. How do i fix this?

Comment: Do you have a stable wifi connection? Also how much bandwith do you receive from your provider? If someone else in your network is browsing or downloading something, do the lag spikes occur then? What about when there is no-one but you on the network? (the obvious question would also be if your hardware can run the game and whether the drivers are up to date.)

Comment: If you also happen to have your wallpaper set to change every 10 seconds you might want to disable that while playing games, my PC drops a few frames whenever it changes the wallpaper and enough frames dropped might get a disconnection warning.

Comment: I have very stable wifi, before this happen i still can downloading while playing dota and receive nice ping, no lag spikes or anything else. And i am not use any wallpaper. I use ASUS ROG G750JZ and there is no problem with hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced the same sort of problem . If its a wifi connection some of the reasons that you get dc'ed are your wi-fi router may have some hardware/software problem . You can sometimes fix this by changing the channel inside wifi settings . You would need to contact the service provider for that . 
The lag can happen if there is some sort of Microwave oven between you and the router and that causes interference and the wifi connection is lost. I am not joking about this as i have actually experienced this and the only logical way was that the wifi is affected due to the oven. Well for this you should just go for an ethernet cable connection than wifi to get a stable connection. Hope this helps

Comment: LOL this is actually true : http://www.howtogeek.com/171869/why-does-running-my-microwave-kill-my-wi-fi-connectivity/

Comment: Can also be things like certain wireless phones, blinking christmas lights, etc

Comment: that moment when you are zipping in as storm vs enemy team and then suddenly "Lost Connection to steam" and all you hope is you arent dead :/ but you are the only one dead and "pls stop feed" appears in chat :/

Comment: @kalina - wireless phones maybe , blinking christmas lights - i am guessing probably not .

Comment: Yesterday engineer from my ISP check wifi router but there is no problem. I think this problem came from my dota.

Comment: I dont think it can be a dota problem from my experience, does your smart phone get the internet connection from the router through wifi or does it get disconnected too when it happens ?

Comment: @Gowtham This is possible there was a guy whose christmas lights knocked out his wifi connection and his next door neighbours as well. Since the AC adapter was interfering with the wifi.

Comment: i meant the lights couldn't , the adapter is the reason :P not the lights :)

Answer (score 0):

It is most probably due to server lag. Most probably, if this had not happened before, it is because too many people are playing, and the steam servers have a hard time responding. Also, if this wasn't persistent, it is not your wifi or connection probelm, it's just steam server problem, so no need to go and change your wifi provider.

However, if this persists, I recommend that you delete steam and redownload Dota 2. If there are other games in your Steam, and would prefer not to download all of them, you can copy the app files excpet for Dota 2 from C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps and paste them back into their original place after Dota 2 have downloaded. (More information here: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2528983)

Hope I helped :)